# If statement with multiple SQL select statements PL/SQL (ORACLE APEX)

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, plsql, oracle-apex

I was wondering if it is possible to have multiple SQL select statements within an if statement using PL/SQL. I wanted different select statements based on the value of another field.

This is what I tried so far but I'm stuck and can't go on

```
    BEGIN
    IF
        :P3_COMPAREWITH <> 'OTHER TABLES'
    THEN
        SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TARGET, TABLE_NAME AS TARGETTABLE 
        FROM ALL_TABLES@target.hu.nl 
        WHERE OWNER = 'TOSAD_2017_2D_TEAM4_TARGET';
    ELSIF
        :P3_COMPAREWITH = 'OTHER TABLES'
    THEN
        SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TARGET, TABLE_NAME AS TARGETTABLE 
        FROM ALL_TABLES@target.hu.nl 
        WHERE OWNER = 'TOSAD_2017_2D_TEAM4_TARGET' AND TABLE_NAME <> :P3_TARGETTABLE;
    END IF;
    END;
```

If someone could help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just `select` statement in PL/SQL is meaningless. You need to define where you want to put selected data, and there are a lot of possibilities (variables, records, collections, cursors...) for this. So tell us what do you want to do with selected data.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly then you can change the way

```
DECLARE
    P3_COMPAREWITH VARCHAR2(128) := '';
    P3_TARGETTABLE VARCHAR2(128) := '';
BEGIN

FOR CUR IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TARGET, TABLE_NAME AS TARGETTABLE
    FROM ALL_TABLES@target.hu.nl 
    WHERE OWNER = 'TOSAD_2017_2D_TEAM4_TARGET' AND ( TABLE_NAME <> P3_TARGETTABLE OR P3_COMPAREWITH <> 'OTHER TABLES' ) )
LOOP
    --use data from cursor
END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to select from two different tables, depending on P3_COMPAREWITH item value. This is most probably NOT supposed to be a PL/SQL but report source or something like that. Doesn't matter if I'm wrong about it, the principle should be the same - in PL/SQL you'd need the INTO clause.

So: create UNION of two queries, and let P3_COMPAREWITH decide which one of them will be used.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TARGET, 
       TABLE_NAME AS TARGETTABLE 
FROM ALL_TABLES@target.hu.nl 
WHERE OWNER = 'TOSAD_2017_2D_TEAM4_TARGET'
  AND :P3_COMPAREWITH <> 'OTHER TABLES'        --> this
--
UNION                                          --> this
--
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TARGET, 
       TABLE_NAME AS TARGETTABLE 
FROM ALL_TABLES@target.hu.nl 
WHERE OWNER = 'TOSAD_2017_2D_TEAM4_TARGET' 
  AND TABLE_NAME <> :P3_TARGETTABLES
  AND :P3_COMPAREWITH = 'OTHER TABLES'         --> this
```